# REST - filtering a value containing apostrophe

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, special-characters

I have the following code:

```
var requestUri = webAbsUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Staff Directory')/Items?$\
        filter=Title eq '" + currentUserEmail + "'&$\
        select=*";
```

It works until it encountered an employee with an apostrophe in the last name.  I tried encodeURI() and encodeURIComponent() but neither worked. I tried searching online and can't seem to find a quick solution.

Example Email: John.O'Doe@domain.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use below:

```
var str = fixedEncodeURIComponent(currentUserEmail);

var requestUri = webAbsUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Staff Directory')/Items?$\
    filter=Title eq '" + str + "'&$\
    select=*";


function fixedEncodeURIComponent(src) {
return encodeURIComponent(src).replace(/[']/g, function (c) {
        return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) + '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    });
}
```

Basically, it duplicates the `'` twice, and enconde each `' => %27`. As a result, the url will show `%27%27` per each `'`

Comment: does it mean I have to replace a single apostrophe with double apostrophe? I'm confused about how charCodeAt(0).toString(16) = 27?

Comment: I found the answer about .toString(16) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786483/char-to-hex-in-javascript):

Comment: Thanks mate. %27%27 fixed it

Comment: The slashes are unnecessary, though. `/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Staff Directory')/Items?$filter=Title eq 'John.O''Doe@domain.com'` on a browser bar URL will work, so just doing the apostrophe replace with `%27%27` within the email address works.

Answer (score 9):

Deepmala's answer will work, but it seems overly complex and hides both the approach and the actual solution. What you're trying to do is replace a single apostrophe with two, but they both have to be URI-encoded.

A simpler and easier-to-understand solution:

```
var str = fixedEncodeURIComponent(currentUserEmail);

var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Staff Directory')/Items?$filter=Title eq '" + str + "'";

function fixedEncodeURIComponent(src) {
    return encodeURIComponent(src).replace(/[']/g, '%27%27');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on **@Deepmala, @Dave Read**, and this **[sharepoint article over here](http://prasannaadavi.com/2014/06/handling-special-characters-in-odata-queries.html#.XlVYNEoo-uX)**.

Here is a method that ensures your **`query` string** is going to **follow the Sharepoint REST url format**, encoding any apostrophe, or any other reserved character:

```
function encodeRestUrl(query: string) {
    return encodeURIComponent(query.replace(/[%]/g, '%25'))
      .replace(/[']/g, '%27%27')
      .replace(/[&]/g, '%26')
      .replace(/[#]/g, '%23')
      .replace(/[?]/g, '%3F')
      .replace(/[/]/g, '%2F')
      .replace(/[+]/g, '%2B');
  }
```

Comment: A little more context on how to use this is needed, IMHO...

Comment: This method ensures your query doenst have characters that make the rest call to fail, like apostrophes, %, and other reserved characters

Comment: What I mean is context on where this goes, how it is called... i.e. What do I do with this thing?!

Comment: Based on the question that is above, this is pretty self explanatory. This is a JS method that you can call passing the `query` mentioned in the question, as the input param, so your queries can contain apostrophes or other special characters

Comment: Ok, I had just never seen a `const` used this way. Usually a `const` doesn't change. I would have made it a `function`, but tow-MAY-tow, tow-MAH-tow, I suppose. Thanks for the explanation, even if a bit snarky.

Comment: Thanks for noticing the syntax error! Just updated it to be a `function` however, its a common practice to declare functions as const, for intance, when using arrow functions as `const f1 = () =>{ return "foo" }` ;)

Comment: Technically, that's assigning an anonymous function to `f1`, the constant variable. And that's actually not really all that common in what I've seen, since again, you usually set a constant variable once and *fo-get-about-it*, but I know some do that sort of thing. I wouldn't call it a best practice, but that's just IMHO.... :shrug:

Comment: how do you declare arrow functions then?

Comment: I believe I've seen it as the form `const f1 = (function() { return "foo"; });`, but neither that nor yours actually assign "foo" to `f1`. You would need a callback function for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400773/javascript-returning-value-from-anonymous-function - but that's EXACTLY why I avoid that kind of thing - it seems to make you believe it will do something it doesn't.

Comment: I am sorry, that is not a javascript arrow function. I suggest you to review the documentation. On the other hand, using `const` for arrow functions is a pretty common practice.

Comment: No shit it's not an arrow function, Mr. Technical. It's another way of writing an ANONYMOUS function. Stop getting technical with me and read up on the various ways you can call a function. Damn. And NO, assigning a function to a `const` is NOT common since a `const` stands for CONSTANT, which means it isn't supposed to change, whereas a function implies that the result will - unless you are returning a constant value (like "foo"), but that would beg the question why you would do any function, arrow or anonymous (which an arrow function IS) when you can just do `const f1 = "foo";` and be done.

Comment: I am sorry @vapcguy, you already went too far away from the main topic of posted answer... anyways, `const f1 = () =>{ return "foo" }` is just an example of an arrow function. It is a good practice to store the function as a const so its logic can't be overwritten. Actually nowadays almost anything in javascript is a const.  I think there is no need to talk about more about const or not const. Good luck in your life ;) and thanks for notifying the typo in code ;)